# How to add a new property to a JSON array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I'm trying to append new properties to some JSON objects not at alls. How can I do that?

For example, this is my JSON array:

```
var eventsArray;

    eventsArray = [

    {
        "title" : "Marco 1",
        "user": "Marco",
        "start" : "2016-01-12T16:00:00-05:00",
        "end" : "2016-01-12T17:00:00-05:00"
    }, {
        "title" : "Marco 2",
        "user": "Marco",
        "start" : "2016-01-12T10:00:00-05:00",
        "end" : "2016-01-12T12:00:00-05:00"
    }, {
        "title" : "Marta 1",
        "user": "Marta",
        "start" : "2016-01-12T09:00:00-05:00",
        "end" : "2016-01-12T10:00:00-05:00"
    }, {
        "title" : "Marta 2",
        "user": "Marta",
        "start" : "2016-01-13T09:00:00-05:00",
        "end" : "2016-01-13T10:00:00-05:00"
    }, {
        "title" : "Veronica 1",
        "user": "Veronica",
        "start" : "2016-01-12T13:00:00-05:00",
        "end" : "2016-01-12T14:00:00-05:00"
    }, {
        "title" : "Veronica 2",
        "user": "Marco",
        "start" : "2016-01-11T13:00:00-05:00",
        "end" : "2016-01-11T14:00:00-05:00"
    }

    ];
```

And then I need to add a new property, such as "color" : "red" to the user Veronica, i.e.:

```
var eventsArray;

eventsArray = [

{
    "title" : "Marco event 1",
    "user": "Marco",
    "start" : "2016-01-12T16:00:00-05:00",
    "end" : "2016-01-12T17:00:00-05:00"
}, {
    "title" : "Marco event 2",
    "user": "Marco",
    "start" : "2016-01-12T10:00:00-05:00",
    "end" : "2016-01-12T12:00:00-05:00"
}, {
    "title" : "Marta event 1",
    "user": "Marta",
    "start" : "2016-01-12T09:00:00-05:00",
    "end" : "2016-01-12T10:00:00-05:00"
}, {
    "title" : "Marta event 2",
    "user": "Marta",
    "start" : "2016-01-13T09:00:00-05:00",
    "end" : "2016-01-13T10:00:00-05:00"
}, {
    "title" : "Veronica event 1",
    "user": "Veronica",
    "start" : "2016-01-12T13:00:00-05:00",
    "end" : "2016-01-12T14:00:00-05:00",
    "color" : "red"
}, {
    "title" : "Veronica event 2",
    "user": "Veronica",
    "start" : "2016-01-11T13:00:00-05:00",
    "end" : "2016-01-11T14:00:00-05:00",
    "color" : "red"
}

];
```

Here above I just added (manually) the "color" : "red" only to the objects having "user" === "Veronica" (the latter two). How I can do this via JavaScript?

I tried some ways without success, such as:

```
eventsArray[4].color = "red";
eventsArray[5].color = "red";
```

or:

```
eventsArray.user["Veronica"].color = "red";
eventsArray.user["Veronica"].color = "red";
```

Is from a few days I'm learning to use JSON.

Please note that in this specific case there will be not any problems having objects with different properties: my program will not explode! :P

Thank you.

Comment: It's working https://jsbin.com/mosuyomuvi/edit?html,js,console

Comment: Simply, try this `eventsArray.forEach(function (item) {if(item.title.indexOf('Veronica') > -1) item.color='red';})`

Comment: This is not *JSON*. It's a Javascript array with objects inside it. JSON is a closely related serialisation format.

Comment: @smallatom: OP isn't wanting to check the `title`, but the `user`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a bunch of ways you could do this.

Here's one easy way:

```
eventsArray.forEach( function( event ) {
    if( event.user == 'Veronica' ) event.color = 'red';
});
```

Of course you will probably want to do this for other users and colors. So it would be best to generalize it into a function:

```
function setUserColor( events, user, color ) {
    events.forEach( function( event ) {
        if( event.user == user ) event.color = color;
    });
}
```

Then you can call it like this:

```
setUserColor( eventsArray, 'Veronica', 'red' );
```

And now you can do the same for other users too:

```
setUserColor( eventsArray, 'Marta', 'green' );
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a basic one.

```
 for(var i = 0; i < eventsArray.length; i++){
   if(eventsArray[i].user === "Veronica" {
      eventsArray[i].color = "red";
   }
 }
```